# difference in speed between tensorflow implementations of mfcc spectrogram

Tags: python, tensorflow, audio-processing, spectrogram, keyword-spotting

I am trying to preprocess audio clips for a keyword spotting task that uses machine learning models.

The first step is to calculate the spectrogram starting from the waveform and in order to do so I have found that there are two ways within the tensorflow framework.

The first one is to use the `tf.signal` library.

This means the functions:

```py
stft = tf.signal.stft(signals, frame_length, frame_step)
spectrogram = tf.abs(stft)
# matrix computed beforehand
tf.tensordot(spectrogram, linear_to_mel_weight_matrix, 1)
log_mel_spectrogram = tf.math.log(mel_spectrogram + 1.e-6)
mfccs = tf.signal.mfccs_from_log_mel_spectrograms(log_mel_spectrogram)
```

The second is to use `tf.raw_ops` library.
This results in the following code:

```py
# spectrogram computation
spectrogram = tf.raw_ops.AudioSpectrogram(
    input=sample,
    window_size=window_size_samples,
    stride=window_stride_samples
    )

# mfcc computation
mfcc_features = tf.raw_ops.Mfcc(
    spectrogram=spectrogram,
    sample_rate=sample_rate,
    dct_coefficient_count=dct_coefficient_count
)
```

The problem is that the second one is much faster (~10x). As you can see from this table.

| Operation | tf.signal | tf.raw_ops |
| --- | --- | --- |
| STFT | 5.09ms | 0.47ms |
| Mel+MFCC | 3.05ms | 0.25ms |

In both cases the same parameters were used (window size, hop size, number of coefficients...).
I have done some tests and the output is the same up to the 3rd decimal digit.

My question is: does someone have some experience with these functions or is someone able to explain this behavior?

Comment: Are you using CPU or GPU to run these? Does the results depend on the size of the audio input (duration of file)?

Comment: I am using a cpu (intel i5 4750 with ubuntu and governor set on performance). The results are obtained by feeding the operations the same input: 1 second duration and 16000hz sampling rate.

Comment: Could you try also with say 0.1 and 10 second durations - there might be overheads, and some functions optimized primarily larger amounts of work per invocation.